# Python - reading checkboxes

Tags: python, html, django

I have a few checkboxes with common name and individual variables (ID).
How can I in python read them as list?
Now I'm using

> checkbox= request.POST["common_name"]

It isn't work properly, checkbox variable store only the last checked box instead of any list or something.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Based on your other question, I'm going to assume this is in Django

Comment: Also, welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 6):

If you were using WebOB, request.POST.getall('common_name') would give you a list of all the POST variables with the name 'common_name'. See the [WebOB](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#query-post-variables) docs for more.

But you aren't - you're using Django. See the [QueryDict](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) docs for several ways to do this - `request.POST.getlist('common_name')` is one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
checkbox = request.POST.getlist("common_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to select objects (say Contact objects) based upon the getlist list, you can do this:

```
selected_ids = request.POST.getlist('_selected_for_action')
object_list = Contact.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_ids)
```